# Android Memory Management - Is my app healthy?

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory

Im really new in android development and had created a simple app that reads some rss xml news feeds from internet, I'm a bit concerned with memory management because each time the app read a xml feed the GC_CONCURRENT is called, the ddms shows that my heap size is 12,133Mb and I had Allocated 11,549Mb (95.15% usage), Im not getting out of memory errors, Im worried because the app has just one activity so far and the memory usage is almost 100%.

Is my app healthy in terms of memory usage?

p.s.: sorry the poor english

```
04-09 17:02:58.731: D/InicioActivity(8998): Categoria: Mundo
04-09 17:02:58.762: D/dalvikvm(8998): null clazz in OP_INSTANCE_OF, single-stepping
04-09 17:02:59.255: D/dalvikvm(8998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 356K, 5% free 11879K/12423K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 30ms
04-09 17:02:59.458: D/InicioActivity(8998): Categoria: Brasil
04-09 17:02:59.505: D/dalvikvm(8998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 515K, 5% free 11831K/12423K,     paused 12ms+2ms, total 30ms
04-09 17:03:00.106: D/dalvikvm(8998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 465K, 5% free 11804K/12423K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 30ms
04-09 17:03:00.153: D/InicioActivity(8998): Categoria: Negócios
04-09 17:02:59.255: D/dalvikvm(8998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 356K, 5% free 11879K/12423K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 30ms
04-09 17:02:59.458: D/InicioActivity(8998): Categoria: Brasil
04-09 17:02:59.505: D/dalvikvm(8998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 515K, 5% free 11831K/12423K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 30ms
04-09 17:03:00.106: D/dalvikvm(8998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 465K, 5% free 11804K/12423K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 30ms
04-09 17:03:00.153: D/InicioActivity(8998): Categoria: Negócios
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done some rss feed programs before. Since I don't know the exact details of your code I'm going to assume you implemented some of the code you found on google.
12 MB is a lot but i hardly think that this has anything to do with the rss feed itself, since most of the codes found online are written very good (and if not I really doubt they would increase your memory to 12mb just by using a simple xml parser).

First take a few things into consideration:

1. normal memory usage for a rss reader would be around 4 MB (at least it was for every one of my parsers)
2. Check your program source code and see if you have any other code that would require additional memory (browser, textures, pictures, graphic engines)
3. Is the xml you're trying to parse at least 1MB in size??? If it is I would advise you to find some other way to parse it.
4. Since you're new here I'm going to suggest that you add a little sample code from now on when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

That's 5% free of the currently allocated heap. It will grow if needed, up until the maximum heap size, after which you will get `OutOfMemoryError`s.

In terms of XML parsing, the general advice is to use `XmlPullParser`, as it comes with the Android framework and has light memory requirements. Parsing with an event-based parser (as opposed to a DOM parser) is harder but the upside is that you don't hold a full representation of the document in memory.